# How to get asp CssClass in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

can you help me to get asp CssClass in jquery in validation rule. here is my code let me know where i did the mistake?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#aspnetForm").validate({
            debug:true,
            ignore:("ignore"),
            rules: {
                <%=txtFirstname.UniqueID %>: {                       
                    required: true
                },
                <%=cmbTitle.UniqueID %>: {
                    required: true
                }
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What has this got to do with CssClass?

Comment: Kevin, I want to ignore the validation for few controls in a form with with CssClass="ignore". so i used ignore in the validate method. please correct me to where i use the "ignore" property in the validation method?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this (source http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#aspnetForm").validate({
        debug:true,
        ignore: ".ignore",
        rules: {
            <%=txtFirstname.UniqueID %>: {                       
                required: true
            },
            <%=cmbTitle.UniqueID %>: {
                required: true
            }
}
```